# C# Reflection: getting a nested objects properties

Tags: c#, reflection

I am having trouble getting a nested objects properties.  For the example I am working with, I have 2 Classes:

```
public class user 
{
  public int _user_id {get; set;}
  public string name {get; set;}
  public category {get; set;}
}

public class category 
{
  public int category_id {get; set;}
  public string name {get; set;}
}
```

Simple enough there, and if I reflect either one of them, I get the proper sets of **GetProperties()**, for example, if I do this:

```
PropertyInfo[] props = new user().GetType().GetProperties();
```

I will get the properties **user_id**, **name** and **category**, and if I do this:

```
PropertyInfo[] props = new category().GetType().GetProperties();
```

I will get the properties **category_id** and **category**; this works just fine.  *But*, this is where I get confused...

As you can see, **category** is the last property of **user**, if I do this

```
//this gets me the Type 'category'
Type type = new user().GetType().GetProperties().Last().PropertyType;
//in the debugger, I get "type {Name='category', FullName='category'}"
//so I assume this is the proper type, but when I run this:
PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetType().GetProperties();
//I get a huge collection of 57 properties
```

Any idea where I am screwing up?  Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing `type.GetType()` you are getting `typeof(Type)`, not the property type.

Just do

```
PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();
```

to get the properties which you want.

However, you should look up properties by their name and not by their order, because the order is not guaranteed to be as you expect it (see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb.aspx)):

> The GetProperties method does not
>   return properties in a particular
>   order, such as alphabetical or
>   declaration order. Your code must not
>   depend on the order in which
>   properties are returned, because that
>   order varies.

Comment: I am not actually looking it up with .Last() - that was just for simplicity in the explanation.

Comment: Very well. Since those questions are indexed by search engines, I'll leave my comment as-is because I feel that people should be aware that using the order must be avoided.

Comment: wow, so simple... I was just thinking too hard (or maybe not enough), thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the GetType() from the type. Your are looking at the properties of the Type type itself.